# PowerApps Filter Items from Last Week

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I'm trying to filter a PowerApps gallery to only return SharePoint items that have a date field with a value equal to last week. My formula is returning an error so I was hoping if someone could kindly help?

```
Filter (weeks,DateDiff(weekcommencing,Today(),Days), >=7 And <=14)
```

Many thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your List is called "weeks", you can use

```
Filter(weeks,'Date 1' <= Today() && 'Date 1' > DateAdd(Today(),-14,Days))
```

Where 'Date 1' is your Date column

**DateAdd** is the function that accepts 'datetime','units to add','units'